# CudaText: After saving, undo is no longer available?

Tags: text-editors, text-editing

In CudaText it appears that there's a problem. If I:

1. Make a change to my text
2. Save the file
3. And try to undo,

then the change isn't undone.

Is this a known problem? Any fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undo in CT is available even after save: set this in user-config:

```
"undo_after_save" : true,
```

(see default-config)

Comment: Thanks. One wonders why this is even an option rather than just working this way :)

Comment: Maybe since it's "false" in many editors?